# Sending email confirmation link in an ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to allow people by registering with their email id, password and confirming password in my asp.net 4.0 application. How can I send the confirmation link to their entered email, and there by showing the profile strength in their individual profiles? with the backend as sql server 2010

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the confirmation link with unique confirmation id as query string parameter in link. When user clicks on that link you can validate that link for -

1. Is link already used?
2. Is link has valid confirmation number.

Then if it is valid link then allow user to confirm there email id. The unique confirmation id needs to be stored in the database for given email id. So that you can validate for it. Also in the same database table you can have additional field where it will record the time stamp when that id is generated and email send to user.

Comment: thank u for ur response. but i'm using sql server as the backend. so timestamp will work in the sql?

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

Authentication and authorization as fundamental part of a web application was tremendously simplified with arrival of .NET 2.0. Basic authentication and authorization can be performed using different DBMS systems. There are numerous examples implementing authentication using Access database. One such example can be found in the article ASP.NET 2.0 Authentication using Access Database. In this article the example implements bare minimum to achieve desired goal, namely authentication and authorization using access database. However, authentication and authorization is only first part of the user management system. Second fundamental part of user management is allowing users to create an account at will. In such instances, users can sign up and become members of the community without administrator intervention. Furthermore, the user should be able to provide contact information (email) so that he/she can be contacted if necessary. Contact information must be verified. This article focuses on very simple ways to achieve such goal.

**CreateUserWizard**

As already suspected, .NET 2.0 provides necessary tools for quick and effective implementation of user registration. The component of interest is CreateUserWizard control that can be found under Login components. CreateUserWizard component provides preformatted set of components that provide the user with opportunity to enter necessary information. By default, CreateUserWizard provides user with option to enter name, password, email, security question, and answer to security question. In addition, CreateUserWizard provides the user with function to reenter the password to confirm user intentions.

In our example, we will focus on minimalistic approach to implement user signup and email conformation. As such we will not implement security question, but rather focus on username, password, and email to be confirmed. This article is continuation of ASP.NET 2.0 authorization using Access Database and it reuses Role and Membership provider code as presented in that article. Here, I’ll only present additions to the above mentioned article. In addition, full source code is included and demonstration can be found in demo section.

**Extending Roles and Membership Providers**

As already mentioned, I’ll focus on additional implementation necessary for CreateUserWizard implementation. Methods implemented in ASP.NET 2.0 authentication and authorization using Access Database are explained in mentioned article. However, there are some modifications that will be stressed at relevant time.

Looking at AccessMembershipProvider, I quickly realized that there are multiple methods that must be implemented to correctly use CreateUserWizardcontrol. First we need to be able to eliminate security question option. In order to eliminate security question, membership provider must return false for RequiresQuestionAndAnswer property of membership provider. Implementation of this property is similar to implementation of connection string property. We simply add variable of type bool that retrieves its value from web configuration file. Web configuration file must contain requiresQuestionAndAnswer as shown below:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="AccessMembershipProvider"
type="AccessProvider.AccessMembershipProvider"
connectionStringName="UsersDB"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"/> 
</providers>
</membership>
```

And the setting is parsed within Initialize method as following:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, 
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
base.Initialize(name, config); 
m_strDBConnection =
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[config["connectionStringName"]].ConnectionString; 
m_bRequiresQuestionAndAnswer = 
(config["requiresQuestionAndAnswer"].ToLower().CompareTo("true") == 0);
}
```

As we can see, the code above simply extracts the setting from the web.config file and applies it to appropriate property. CreateUserWizard control reads the same property and displays security question according to the property value. Now that security question does not have to be entered, we can look at what happens when user enters the data and tries to create a user. Through experiment, I realized that the AccessMembershipProvider method CreateUser is called (obviously). Intuitively, I concluded that this method is responsible for the code that adds the user to the database. Following is method implementation:

public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email,

```
string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, 
bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, 
out MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
MembershipUser user = null; 
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_strDBConnection))
{
try
{
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users " + 
"(UUSERNAME, UPASSWORD, EMAIL, PROVIDER_KEY) "+
"VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4)", 
conn); 
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", email);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param4", guid.ToString()); 
conn.Open(); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
string[] users = {username}; 
Roles.AddUsersToRole(users, "User"); 
conn.Close(); 
user = new MembershipUser("AccessMembershipProvider",
username, guid, email, null, null, false, false,
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now); 
status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
}
}
return user;
}
```

CreateUser method simply adds the user to the database and returns MembershipUser object filled with the information as entered in CreateUserWizard. My first implementation of the method did not include adding the user to the “User” group using role provider. However, later investigation showed that the user was simply added without group assignment. Realizing that the user must be in a group, I added the following implementation to AccessRoleProvider code:

```
public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
{
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_strDBConnection))
{
try
{
for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; ++i)
{
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UsersInRoles "+
"(ROLE_NAME, UUSERNAME) "+
"VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)",
conn); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", roleNames[i]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", usernames[i]); 
conn.Open(); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
conn.Close();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
}
```

Now that the user is added to the database and assigned to appropriate group, we need to implement code to confirm user information, particularly email. Searching through MSDN documentation I found that CreateUserWizard provides method for automatic email notification. However, such approach was not appropriate because of lack of information provided within the event. Our conformation will utilize GUID that is written to DB when the user is created. The user will be activated only when the activation with such GUID is performed. Finding out GUID was impractical using send email event and easier solution was found, namely CreatedUser event of CreateUserWizard component.

**Email Notification**

As already mentioned, the user should be able to use the account only after successful email conformation. For conformation, the user should receive an email containing the link that will automatically activate the account. Once the account is activated, the account is ready to be used. Following is CreatedUser event implementation:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CreateUserWizard wizard = (CreateUserWizard)sender;
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(wizard.UserName); 
if (user != null)
{
try
{
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtpServer");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Send("yourEmail", user.Email, "Account Conformation Email", 
"hst/Confirm.aspx?id="+user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
}
```

Implementation of email notification is very simple. This is due to the fact that .NET library provides very simple means to communicate with any SMTP server. It is important to note the line smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true. In this way, smtpClient object looks into web.config for SMTP server settings, i.e. username, password, and the host to be used. Following section is expected by SmtpClient object to be present in web.config file:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp>
<network
host="smtp.hst.com "
userName="username"
password="password" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Settings are self explanatory. The smtpClient simply needs the host name, username, and password to be used. Once the user is created, CreatedUser event is raised and email is sent. The content of the email is simply a link to Confirm.aspx page with an id parameter. The id parameter is GUID assigned specifically for that user. It is important to note that username could be used too, but GUID provides slightly more security.

Another extension necessary for CreatedUser event to function properly is capability of AccessMembershipProvider object to be able to provide user information based on username. In order to achieve such functionality, AccessMembershipProvider contains method that takes username as parameter and reads user information from database. Following is implementation:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
MembershipUser user = null; 
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_strDBConnection))
{
try
{
/* Create command */
OleDbCommand command = 
new OleDbCommand("SELECT UUSERNAME, PROVIDER_KEY, EMAIL FROM Users " +
"WHERE UUSERNAME=@Param1", conn); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", username); 
/* Open connection */
conn.Open(); 
/* Run query */
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
/* Check if we have something */
bool bResult = reader.HasRows; 
if (bResult)
{
reader.Read();
user = new MembershipUser("AccessMembershipProvider", reader.GetString(0), 
new Guid(reader.GetString(1)),
reader.GetString(2), "", "", true, false, 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now,
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
}
/* Close connection */
conn.Close(); 
return user;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
return user;
}
}
```

Once again, the implementation is trivial. We simply find info about user with specified username by running query against our users table.

**Email Confirmation**

Once the email is sent the user receives an email with a link to confirm his/her signup and email. The link is of the form http://"hst"/Confirm.aspx?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is GUID determined in CreateUser method. Once the user clicks on the email the browser loads Confirm.aspx page with appropriate parameter. As suspected, Confirm.aspx is responsible for account activation. The account activation is performed by modifying ACTIVATED flag within user table. Following is Confirm.aspx implementation:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersDB"].ConnectionString))
{
try
{
OleDbCommand command = 
new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET ACTIVATED=@Param1 "+
"WHERE PROVIDER_KEY=@Param2", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", true);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", Request.QueryString["id"]); 
conn.Open(); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
conn.Close(); 
Response.Write("Your account has been activated. "+
"Please log in <a href='Default.aspx'>here</a>");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
}
}
```

The implementation is self explanatory. The code simply modifies activated flag of the user with specified GUID.

At this point it is important to state somewhat obvious fact. The AccessMembershipProvider’s ValidateUser method must be modified to consider activated flag. In other words, only activated users can be validated and consequently logged in. For completeness, following is the implementation:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(m_strDBConnection))
{
try
{
/* Create command */
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UUSERNAME, UPASSWORD FROM Users " +
"WHERE UUSERNAME=@Param1 " +
"AND UPASSWORD=@Param2 " +
"AND ACTIVATED=@Param3",
conn); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", true); 
/* Open connection */
conn.Open(); 
/* Run query */
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
/* Check if we have something */
bool bResult = reader.HasRows; 
/* Close connection */
conn.Close(); 
return bResult;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
return false;
}
}
```

**Access Database**

Access database utilized is extended version of the database utilized in ASP.NET 2.0 Forms Authentication article with addition of GUID and ACTIVATED fields. GUID is stored in PROVIDER_KEY field. In addition, some fields like username and password had to be renamed because of the conflict with Access DB system.

[Source](http://www.amergerzic.com/post/AccessEmailConfirmation.aspx)

[Click here to demo](http://www.isscode.com/signup/)